# Can I take the mean of an indirect measurement?

Tags: regression, mean, error

I've been told that one shouldn't take the mean of indirect variables. Specially, I should not give the standard error as the error of the mean.

To give an example, if I'm using Ohm's law $V=RI$ and I have measured $V$ for several values of $I$,I could calculate the resistence as $R=V/I$. I would get different values of $R$ and  according to what I have written above, I wouldn't be able to do anything more.

On the other hand, I could do a linear regression on $V$ and $I$ (I'm not sure if that's the correct way to say it). So it seems that in this case the linear regression would be an alternative to the mean, but I don't know if it is always possible (for example, when I have many variables).

So if I have a set of calculated values, is there any way to combine them or should I just leave a table (or graph) of all the values?

Answer (score 1):

You have been told right.  Linear regression is a good approach here.